# Querying RavenDB

Tags: c#, .net, ravendb

I am able to insert and delete data in a RavenDB store. I am also able to run queries that return multiple documents.

I am however unable to load data using `session.Load<Book>("books/0")` which returns `null`. Additionally, I get an `InvalidOperationException` when I try and run a query that searches for a book with a given ID but this particular behavior is expected.

Is there anything I am missing when fetching the doc?

Code Block:

```
using (var session = DocumentStoreHolder.Store.OpenSession())
{
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
        var doc = session.Load<Book>(i); 
        Console.WriteLine(doc);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Do you *have* a document with the id `books/0`?
Typically document ids start with 1, so you'll have `books/1`, etc.

Comment: I use my own ids and made it start at 0. Is that something I should avoid?

Comment: This seems to have helped. I removed the 0 Id and it works great. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

It's been a little while since I used Raven but I believe you need to use a Query not Load.

```
using (var session = DocumentStoreHolder.Store.OpenSession())
{
    var books = session.Query<Book>().ToList();
    books.ForEach(book =>
    {
         //Note that book is an object, write out one of it's properties
         Console.WriteLine(book.Name); 
    });

    //or get single book:
    var id = 1;
    var book = session.Query<Book>()
       .FirstOrDefault(x => x.ID == id); 
}
```

Comment: Note that by just doing a `ToList()` on a `Query<Book>()`, you're limiting the result set to 128 items (which is by design).

Comment: Is there a way to limit the query by Id? Thats the challenge I am having with using queries. I tried `from books in session.Query<Book>()
                              where books.Id.Equals(id)
                              select books;` but the InvalidMethodException is thrown.

Comment: @carl_plat I have updated the answer to show a query by id (assuming you have a property ID on your book object).

Comment: Thanks @StephenBrickner. That query, however, throws a System.InvalidOperationException (in Raven.Client.Lightweight.dll). Seems like the authors discourage this approach to loading objects.

Comment: For a single document you want to use Load, not Query (please refer to https://ravendb.net/docs/article-page/3.0/csharp/client-api/session/loading-entities).

Comment: @ricardobrandão the query is getting multiple books. The second example is is just taking one from the list.

Comment: Ok. I get it now. However that doesn't answer the question since Carl was already able to query the collection but unable to load (single) documents. Perhaps you could express the difference between query and load in your answer? Because, as is, it might be misleading.